# How many iterations of code analysis does c# compiler performs before it starts code generation?

Tags: c#, compilation, compiler-construction

The compiler internally builds an AST of the program given, what does it do next? How many things does it take in account (e.g. type definitions, methods, fields, locals and so on)?

Comment: http://sourceroslyn.io -- take a look

Comment: and check [here](https://discoverdot.net/projects/roslyn)

Comment: I'm guessing it would be pretty low because it is JITing.